# what is wrong with stretching of my usercontrol

Tags: .net, wpf

I want that the picture that comes from the usercontrol will stratch all over the yellow background and not only in that thin line there .

I have stretched every possible thing there but still i have this problem

my main window

```
<Window x:Class="DBTool.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:View="clr-namespace:DBTool.View"
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:DBTool.ViewModel"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="332" Width="528"  >

<Window.Resources>
    <!-- These four templates map a ViewModel to a View. -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:SelectDataBaseViewModel}">
        <View:SelectDataBase />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:MySqlPageViewModel}">
        <View:MySqlPageView />
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>



<Grid ShowGridLines="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ToolBar  Grid.Row = "0" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="toolBar1"  Width="Auto" DockPanel.Dock="Top"  />
    <!-- <View:SelectDataBase x:Name="DetailView"/>-->



    <Grid  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row = "2"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Background="Azure" Margin="10"   Command="{Binding Path=MoveNextCommand}" >Next</Button>

            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Background="Azure" Margin="10" Command="{Binding Path=MovePreviousCommand}">Previous</Button>

        </Grid>
        <Border Background="Yellow" Grid.Row = "1">
             <HeaderedContentControl VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Content="{Binding Path=CurrentPage}" Header="{Binding Path=CurrentPage.DisplayName}" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
```

the user control

```
<UserControl x:Class="DBTool.View.SelectDataBase"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" >

<UserControl.Background  >
    <ImageBrush  Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="..\Resources\DBSelection.jpg" ></ImageBrush >
</UserControl.Background >

<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <!--<RadioButton Content="MySQL" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,112,0,0" Name="radioButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <RadioButton Content="MsSQL" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,134,0,0" Name="radioButton2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />-->
    <ItemsControl FontWeight="Normal" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableBeanTypes}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RadioButton Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" GroupName="BeanType" Margin="2,3.5"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

</Grid>
```

will be glad for any help , just cannot solve this out :-(

[image: My code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your HeaderedContentControl does not explicitly set the Height it defaults to Auto which is defined by your grid height in the user control. And because that also is not set then it will be set to the size of the ItemsControl, which in this case is only the height of the 2 radio buttons.  To fix it you must explicitly set the height of ItemsControl.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess after a quick glance is the `RowDefinitions` in the main window:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Perhaps try changing the height of all of them to a fixed number, see if that fixes it?

Comment: sorry but you are wrong , because the border is taking the right space , but what in the border not stretching .

Answer (score 0):

In the ImageBrush give Uniform instead of UnifromToFill